# Storing derived classes in a vector of base class

Tags: vector, derived-class

I have seen several versions of my question, but I still cannot find an answer that works. I have defined a base class called TwoPort and two derived classes called Reflector and Waveguide as follows:

```
#include <vector>

class TwoPort
{
public:
    TwoPort() { yeast = ywest = 0.0; }
    ~TwoPort() {}

    double getyeast() { return yeast; }
    double getywest() { return ywest; }

    virtual void step(double xeast, double xwest);

protected:
    double yeast;
    double ywest;
};

class Reflector :
    public TwoPort
{
public:
    Reflector() { Gamma = 0.0; }
    ~Reflector() {}

    void step(double xeast, double xwest) override;

    void setReflection(double G) { Gamma = G; }

private:
    double Gamma;
};

class Waveguide :
    public TwoPort
{
public:
    Waveguide() { oldest = 0; }
    ~Waveguide() {}

    void step(double xeast, double xwest) override;

    void setDelay(unsigned int delay);

private:
    std::vector<double> eastBuffer, westBuffer;
    unsigned int oldest;
};
```

My goal is to create a vector containing a mixture of Reflectors and Waveguides. Based on the answers to previous questions like mine, I have tried a number of approaches, but so far none have worked. For example:

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<TwoPort>> tpcascade;
    
    tpcascade.emplace_back(new Reflector);
    tpcascade.emplace_back(new Waveguide);
    tpcascade.emplace_back(new Reflector);
    tpcascade[0]->setRefection(0.25);
}
```

In this case, the compiler does not recognize the setReflection method. So I tried this:

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<TwoPort>> tpcascade;
    
    auto ref = std::make_unique<Reflector>();
    ref->setReflection(0.25);
    tpcascade.emplace_back(ref);
}
```

In this case I can set the reflection but I get a lengthy and complex error message about the emplace statement.

Help!

Answer (score 1):

Did some research and tried a variation on the second approach above:

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<TwoPort>> tpcascade;
    
    auto ref = std::make_unique<Reflector>();
    ref->setReflection(0.25);
    tpcascade.push_back(std::move(ref));
}
```

Switching to shared_ptr seems to work too, and is a bit cleaner:

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<TwoPort>> tpcascade;

    auto ref = std::make_shared<Reflector>();
    ref->setReflection(0.25);
    tpcascade.push_back(ref);
}
```

This also seems to work, but seems risky to me:

```
tpcascade.push_back(std::make_shared<Reflector>());
std::dynamic_pointer_cast<Reflector>(tpcascade[0])->setReflection(0.25);
```